# OpenLayers: Modify features without virtual vertices?

Tags: openlayers-2, features

When using the *modify feature* functionality of OpenLayers, I get the option to move the individual vertices around.

But I also get a set of *virtual vertices* - each vertex located on the edge between the original vertices. The virtual vertices allow me to kind of locally *subdivide* the existing polygon.

[image]

I can see that this *feature* is neat, but in many situations I don't want the user to be able to do local subdivision of the polygon - I want to maintain the original set of vertices while allowing the user to change the position of each of the vertices.

Is that possible with the existing OpenLayers controls?

Answer (score 4):

The vertices are stored in two different properties of the ModifyFeature control - [virtual vertices](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.virtualVertices) and [vertices](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.vertices).

You could check which group the vertex belonged to in the [dragVertex](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.dragVertex) event, and if it is in the virtual vertex array then ignore it.

If you also set the [virtualStyle](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.virtualStyle) of the control then these virtual vertices will be invisible.

Alternatively you could add an event handler for the selectFeature function and destroy the vertices with code similar to:

```
myControl.layer.removeFeatures(myControl.virtualVertices, {silent: true});
myControl.virtualVertices = [];
```

Ignoring drags on the virtual vertices, and hiding them from the user may be simpler to implement though.

Comment: Even though I set a transparent *virtualStyle* I'll still get the *move* cursor when hovering a virtual vertex - right? I don't get though, why they haven't included a boolean `useVirtualVertices`. I could add it my self, but I would have to maintain it when upgrading OpenLayers.

Comment: You could always extend the control to add this functionality so you would not have to worry (or worry less) about upgrades. Did you try the cursor property of the virtualStyle?

Comment: I haven't tried the *cursor* property. I am still at the planning phase and just wanted to hear if the answer to my question is yes or if I need to take another route.

Comment: Obviously, the answer is *yes*. Geographika gave you already many informations to prove/do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just set [createVertices](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.createVertices) on your ModifyFeature control to `false`.

Example:

```
    var modifyControl = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectorLayer);
    modifyControl.createVertices = false;
```

Here is a live [demo](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/modify-feature.html).

Comment: I seems like it is supported now, it wasn't more than two years ago when I posted the question :)

Thanks for informing us!